# maven gae plugin questions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, maven

I'm having some issues making the maven google app engine plugin work properly.

First of all, I'm not even sure if the archetype I'm using is the correct one, their examples show version 0.7.0 but it seems like never versions exist (i tried 0.9.1 and that works), where can I find a overview of what versions of the plugin is available?

Secondly, the archetype seems.. messy, I don't like the package structure and it doesn't seem to actually include the GAE and GWT dependencies. I have to manually add them to my project in Eclipse, which kind of defeats the purpose of using maven. And how come they are breaking the gwt maven plugin? I know that one includes the actual gwt jars as maven dependencies?

I'm fairly new to Maven, but I have been using the gwt maven plugin for a while, and I'm very happy with everything about it. Is there any way I could just their archetype to do the base project and add the gae plugin to it?

**UPDATE**

I suspect the problem I'm seeing with the GAE maven plug-in is in regards to undefined properties in the POM. I have no idea if its due to error these aren't set-up or if its due to me actually have to manually set them up. The documentation on this plugin is sparse.

Thanks for the answer below, but I really don't want to add another archetype into play. I think the best solution for me is to try and adapt a GWT maven project manually, to include support for GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the archetype like so :

http://code.google.com/p/gae-mvn-archetype/

to generate a GAE project template.Then manually added my other dependencies. This got me a usable project which I can deploy to GAE and everything.

Also, for Eclipse importing, once the template project was done, I've imported it into eclipse using the m2_eclipse plugin :

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html

(note that i've imported it into Eclipse as a Maven project, NOT as an Eclipse whatever project)

This imported the thing into eclipse with all the necessary dependencies and without errors.